# Pentaho 5.0.1 Send scheduled reports in Email Body

Tags: email, pentaho, schedule, xaction

How do I send scheduled email with reports within email body. The documention available is not for version 5.0.1 Community Edition. It appears I may have to use xaction (was hoping not) . However I do not know how to go about it? Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pentaho Provides a sample xaction script (`email_inventory_inline_HTML.xaction`) that does this. Script is in directory:`biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\bi-developers\reporting\unified-file-format` for older versions but under `Public/Bi Developer Examples/Reporting/PRPT Samples` .

I used the Design Studio to modify the xaction script to suit my needs. The Design Studio was not perfect so I had to recheck the generated xaction script for accuracy,

It  work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for [scheduling reports](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/puc_user_guide/task_about_scheduling_reports.html) by email.

Please remmember it is the enterprise version (which is better documented) and some details might change in the community version.

Comment: I am using the CE. The docs do not have information about how to get the scheduled report to appear in the email body instead of as an attachment. That's my headache